# Background Color CSS flickering before Angular ng-view loads

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-routing

Frontend question. I'm building an Angular application using ngRoute and ng-view to handle page displays. The body of my main index.html page has a background color gradient.

For some reason, the page will noticeably flicker a version of the site with just the gradient before loading the html partial views. The flicker looks like the below.

[image: Background Color Flicker]

After the load (which takes 1 second), the page displays normally as below.

[image: After Load]

My page's body has the below css:

```
/* Background Color */
body {
    background: #ECE9E6; 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to top, #ECE9E6 , #FFFFFF); 
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ECE9E6 , #FFFFFF); 
}
```

How can I avoid this flicker?

Comment: Have you tried using ngCloak?

Comment: Yeah I tried this, but it didn't seem to work. I watched a video on ng-cloak and it looks like it helps prevent variables from displaying as {{varName}}. Not sure if it applies here as well.

I tried using it as:

<body ng-cloak>

Is there a different way I should be using it?